# How to convert to laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel

I need to convert this query to laravel, Help.

```
UPDATE table_name
 SET usercontact_status = CASE
     WHEN usercontact_status = 0 THEN 2
     WHEN usercontact_status = 16 THEN 64
     WHEN usercontact_status = 32 THEN 128
     WHEN usercontact_status = 4 THEN 256
 END WHERE usercontact_value = "456"
```

Comment: Have you created any models yet? Did you try anything?

Comment: It seems like you haven't tried anything before asking since a lot of resources can be found regarding this. try [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) and please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before asking so that your answer would be more likely to be answered than downvoted.

Comment: Yes i did create model,

eibersji, Actually this is what i tried,

DB::update('
UPDATE '.UserContacts::getTableName().'
SET usercontact_status = CASE
WHEN usercontact_status = 0 THEN 2
WHEN usercontact_status = 16 THEN 64
WHEN usercontact_status = 32 THEN 128
WHEN usercontact_status = 4 THEN 256
END
WHERE usercontact_value = "'.$code->usercontact_value.'"
');

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited answer for you question

```
switch ($usercontact_status) {
    case 0:
        $value = 2;
        break;
    case 16:
        $value = 64;
        break;
    case 32:
        $value = 128;
        break;
    case 4:
        $value = 256;
        break;
}
```

Your query will be somewhat like this

```
$query = Model::where('usercontact_value','456')->where('usercontact_status',$usercontact_status)->update([
    'usercontact_status' => $value
]);
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: This is what i follow you,

UserContacts::where('usercontact_value',$code->usercontact_value)
       ->update([
        'usercontact_status' => '
        CASE
         WHEN usercontact_status = 0 THEN 2
         WHEN usercontact_status = 16 THEN 64
         WHEN usercontact_status = 32 THEN 128
         WHEN usercontact_status = 4 THEN 256
        END
        '
       ]);

Is this correct